# Advise for migrating from Android 6.0?

Tags: google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow, amazon-kindle-app

I have an old Lenovo T3-850F that has fallen out of support; and I thought that maybe I should migrate it to a new device with a higher version.

What do I need to do to do this properly and not loose the things I've bought from the Google Play Store / Amazon Kindle, etc?

Comment: If your concern is **only** paid apps from Play Store and Kindle, there is nothing to worry as long as you sign in on the new device with the same Google credentials. You can download again those apps and use them

Comment: Additionally [back up your apps](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/android-marshmallow-auto-backup-apps/) to Google, so that transition is easier. Note that all apps may not be backed up and therefore not restored